# Python, list index out of range error

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to test a simple 2d map coordinate generator in python. It creates a Tile objects with x and y array so that I can access the coordinates and modify their properties.

This creates the map object and fills it with tiles in a 2D coordinate plane

```
map = [[ Tile(True)
    for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT) ]
        for x in range(MAP_WIDTH) ]
```

The tile class:

```
class Tile:
    #a tile of the map and its properties
    def __init__(self, blocked, type, owner, block_sight = None):
        self.blocked = blocked
        self.type = type
        self.owner = owner 
        if block_sight is None: block_sight = blocked
        self.block_sight = block_sight
```

I attempted to have the program read a text file character by character to create a map. It would insert an object at the coordinates provided by mapx and mapy into the map.

```
mapx = 0
mapy = 0
filename = str(mapn) + '.txt'
new_map = [[ Tile(True, 0, 0)
         for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT) ]
       for x in range(MAP_WIDTH) ]
with open(filename) as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if not c:
            return new_map
        elif (c == '#'):
            new_map[mapx][mapy].blocked = False
            new_map[mapx][mapy].block_sight = True
            new_map[mapx][mapy].type = 0
            new_map[mapx][mapy].owner = 0
```

(After several more elifs)

```
if(mapx < MAP_WIDTH):
    mapx += 1
elif(mapy < MAP_HEIGHT):
    mapy += 1
    mapx = 0
```

When running this, I get this error: IndexError: list index out of range. 
It says the line

```
 new_map[mapx][mapy].blocked = False
```

is to fault for this. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show a *minimal* example that shows your problem? Otherwise the only thing we can say is that you're failing to correctly check when the index is in range.

Comment: Are you sure that your file has exactly `mapx * mapy` characters?

Comment: @tom Oh yes. If the file has more lines, then `mapx` is never resetted to `0`, and with the next loop its value is `MAP_WIDTH` which is out of range. Adding an `else: break` or `else: mapx = 0` should solve the `IndexError` (even though I think there is a smarter way to read that file to avoid this thing).

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of some other question.

Answer (score 2):

The after initialization the outer list will have have `MAP_WIDTH` elements with indices from 0 to `MAP_WIDTH-1`. Similarly, each inner list will have indices from 0 to `MAP_HEIGHT-1`.

Consider what happens when `mapx = MAP_WIDTH-1`; ie is at the end of the list using your code:

```
if(mapx < MAP_WIDTH):
    mapx += 1
....
```

The value of `mapx` will become larger than the upper bound of the list.

The test should be `mapx < MAP_WIDTH-1` to resolve this. The test in the elif also needs to be   changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more pythonic if you first read the file and create a list [ ... (xi, yi) ... ] and then create a loop over the (xi,yi) to instanciate the Tile objects.
This way, you would avoid to have to think about the list indices.

Just my 2 cts...